# R - dplyr stylised print or paste

Tags: r, dplyr

I was wondering if it was possible to "stylised" `dplyr` results.

Imagine I am running a bootstrapping mean procedure 10 times, each time selecting 2 cases

```
library(dplyr) 

for(i in 1:10){
   m = mean( mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), size = 2), 'cyl']  )
   print(paste('Mean Boot', i, ':', m)) 
}

[1] "Mean Boot 1 : 8"
[1] "Mean Boot 2 : 7"
[1] "Mean Boot 3 : 8"
[1] "Mean Boot 4 : 4"
...
```

I was wondering how I could print such results from a `dplyr` code.

Something like

```
for(i in 1:10){
   mtcars %>% sample_n(2) %>% 
   summarise(m = mean(cyl)) %>% 
   print(paste('Mean Boot', i, ':', m)) 
}
```

Any clue ?

Comment: I don't really see a need for `summarise()`.  How about `for(i in 1:10){
    mtcars %>% sample_n(2) %>% .$cyl %>% mean %>% paste("Mean Boot", i, ":", .) %>% print
}`

Comment: That what I am looking for, first paste and then print. I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
for(i in 1:10){ 
   mtcars %>%
   sample_n(2) %>% 
   summarise(m= paste('Mean Boot', i, ':', mean(cyl)))  %>%
   .$m %>%
   print 
 } 
#[1] "Mean Boot 1 : 6"
#[1] "Mean Boot 2 : 5"
#[1] "Mean Boot 3 : 7"
#[1] "Mean Boot 4 : 6"
#[1] "Mean Boot 5 : 8"
#[1] "Mean Boot 6 : 6"
#[1] "Mean Boot 7 : 4"
#[1] "Mean Boot 8 : 7"
#[1] "Mean Boot 9 : 8"
#[1] "Mean Boot 10 : 6"
```